# Provide a Flutter WebApp from within an iOS Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'd like to create a flutter IOS app which stores data and allows to edit it within the iOS app.

Then the iOS app be able to provide a webserver [start an internal webserver e.g. using [jaguar]](https://pub.dev/packages/jaguar) and serve a WebApp, which operates on the same data on the iDevice.

Idea: Make the iDevice the only data store. And allow a e.g. windows client to access the data on the iOS device using a web interface [and not require it to push it into a cloud].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Flutter jaguar](https://pub.dev/packages/jaguar) to make it work, have you tried to run the example ?

I think what would be very challenging is that IOS kill background processes, so to use your IOS app as a (reliable) server in the background would be impossible (if reliability, and it should, is a concern), only audio streaming apps would not be killed. So it means you will have to run your server at all time in the foreground

And not to mention that if your phone is out of battery it would also stop working (but of course, you are aware of that, and that's true that if connect to charger, it could perfectly act as a server, as I have tested myself!).

NB: If it's for some serious project, not a fun personal project/challenge, I advise you to reconsider and what you could still do is to manage your server data from the IOS app (meaning that you would send data on on-premise or cloud server like Firebase). But as you stated in your question you are looking to make it work on the Iphone device.